# Set Electron origin to domain

Tags: http, axios, electron, electron-builder

I'm building an Electron application (electron builder) and when deploying if I look at the dev tools it just says app:// at the top and also when sending any http(s) requests the origin is app://.

I have a feeling this has been a cause with some cookies not setting and CORS issues and I have been having.

In the `createWindow` function in background.js theirs a section that runs if in production with default as:

```
createProtocol('app')
win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
```

Setting that to my domain and building give just a blank window with the dev console saying chrome-error://chromewebdata

[chrome-error when setting what I assumed to be the origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkBes.png)

Comparing this with Discord the top bar in dev tools says the discord website and also all requests have the origin of Discord.com
[Discord dev tool header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyNaK.png) which makes me think this is app level rather than just http request level (axios/fetch)

Any ideas on how to change the origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research into creating deep links, I've found that I basically needed my own protocol to do it (makes sense really).

So went to the documentation for Vue CLI Electron Builder and looked at the config section (https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/configuration.html#changing-the-file-loading-protocol)

When electron:build is ran, it pulls in the options from vue.config.js. Adding in:

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
       customFileProtocol: 'myCustomProtocol://./'

    }
  }
}
```

And then also updating the `win.loadURL('myCustomProtocol://./index.html')` in background.js assigns the custom protocol to the app (all of this is in the documentation linked above)